# Multiple TYPO3s behind nginx issue

Tags: nginx, typo3, reverse-proxy, typo3-6.2.x

I want to host several TYPO3s behind an nginx reverse proxy using the following structure:

Internal server (apache):

```
http://some.internal.ip/site1
http://some.internal.ip/site2
http://some.internal.ip/site3
```

External server (nginx, reverse proxy):

```
http://site1.mydomain.com
http://site2.mydomain.com
http://site3.mydomain.com
```

So here're the relevant parts of my nginx.conf

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name site1.mydomain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded_Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass              http://some.internal.ip/site1$request_uri;
        }
    }
    ...
    server {
        (like above with site2 and so on)
        ...
    }
```

(I quickly rewrote the configuration from https to http in order not to make things more complicated then necessary.)

Now, the nginx-Part of this seems to work - it's the Typo3 that seems to cause the trouble as all elements on the site are referred to as

```
http://some.internal.ip/site1/example.php
```

instead of

```
http://site1.mydomain.com/example.php
```

I'm aware of

```
[SYS][reverseProxyIP]
```

and

```
[SYS][reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue]
```

which I set accordingly, but that doesn't seem to work - which in turn is what should be expected based on my understanding.

Is there another way to approach this issue or am I simply trying something that simply can't be done this way?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `config.baseUrl = http://some.internal.ip/site1/` on your website?

If you are, I recommend you to use `config.absRefPrefix = /` instead.

See also [Søren Mallings article from 2013](https://buzz.typo3.org/people/soeren-malling/article/baseurl-is-dead-long-live-absrefprefix/) which is still correct.